# Where clause not working with the ClickHouse view

Tags: view, clickhouse

I am trying to create a view on a source table and then select the data for a specific timestamp range from the view and put it into the targe table.

We have a source table:

1 Million rows are pushed to the source table which corresponds to data from 1 January to 31 January.

```sql
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS source(
      CELL          String,
      TIMESTAMP     DateTime,
      COUNTER1      Float32,
      COUNTER2      Float32,
      COUNTER3      Float32,
      COUNTER4      Float32,
      COUNTER5      Float32,
      COUNTER6      Float32,
      InsertionTime DateTime DEFAULT now(),      /* Insertion Time */
      QHour         DateTime DEFAULT toStartOfFifteenMinutes(TIMESTAMP)
    ) ENGINE=ReplacingMergeTree()
    PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(TIMESTAMP)
    ORDER BY (QHour, TIMESTAMP, CELL)
    SETTINGS index_granularity = 31768
```

Now, we created a view on the source table.

```sql
    CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS myView
      AS SELECT
        CELL,
        QHour,
        toStartOfFifteenMinutes(TIMESTAMP)      AS ViewQHour,
        100 * sum(COUNTER1) / sum(COUNTER2)     AS KPI1
      FROM ( 
        SELECT
            CELL,
            TIMESTAMP,
            any(QHour) as QHour
            argMax(COUNTER1, InsertionTime)     AS COUNTER1,
            argMax(COUNTER2, InsertionTime)     AS COUNTER2
        FROM ThreeGCell
        GROUP BY TIMESTAMP, CELL, QHour)
    GROUP BY ViewQHour, CELL
    ORDER BY ViewQHour, CELL
```

Now, on the view I need to select the data for a time period from view: 1 January to 10th January.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM myView 
WHERE QHour >= toDateTime('2020-01-01 00:00:00') AND QHour <= toDateTime('2020-01-10 00:00:00')
```

But the select query on the view adds all 1 million rows to the target table which is whole January data while I am looking for data for specific period only 1 January to 10th January.

**I have following questions:**

1. Can we modify the query on the view to only process the specific time period?
2. Can we generate a view on the latest dataset pushed in the source table on the fly? 
   I mean we have only the filtered dataset from source table and use the filtered data in the view?
   Can such filters be modified to use different time ranges?
   For example, we have data from 1 January to 10th January in the view.
   Then in second run, we have data from 11th Janury to 20th January in the view.

Comment: Try to apply [enable_optimize_predicate_expression](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#enable-optimize-predicate-expression)-param for view like this: *CREATE VIEW .. ORDER BY .. SETTINGS enable_optimize_predicate_expression = 1*

Comment: @vladimir : I performed the changes you suggested. But the view still has 1 million rows. When I perform a select on the view, the select is still processing the 1 million rows. The results are correct. But what I am looking for it to process only the limited number of rows from the view as per the timestamp filter in the select query.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS myView
....
ORDER BY ViewQHour, CELL
```

Most of databases forbid to create view with `ORDER BY` unfortunately CH does not. It was a mistake in initial design to allow to create such views.

`ORDER BY` cancels predicate pushdown because it corrupts results in some cases (optimizer still is very weak and does't understand cases with runningDiff() and neighbour().

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/9425#issuecomment-592658368